# C code that finds the number pi using leibniz formula

Tags: c

I am asked to write the C code that finds the number pi using the Leibniz formula.
However, the result should be 3.14 but result turns 3.23. What is the reason for this?

```
 //Calculating the value of PI

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

//function main begins program execution
int main( void )
{
    float pi = 0;
    size_t k,n;

    for ( n = 0 , k = 0; n <= 10 , k <= 10; n++ ,k++) {

        pi +=  ( pow( -1, n ) * 4 )/ ( 2 * k + 1 );
    }//end for

    printf(" pi is %.2f\n",pi );

    getch();
    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: Leibniz notation is just a way to represent a derivative as dy/dx. It has nothing to do with calculating pi.

Comment: 1: `%.2f` -> `%f`. 2: use more iterations.

Comment: @interjay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: @Damien That's not Leibniz notation, it's a formula also named after Leibniz.

Comment: BTW: why do you have `n` and `k`? You can remove `k` alltogether and use `pi +=  ( pow( -1, n ) * 4 )/ ( 2 * n + 1 );`

Comment: You can find details on the convergence of the series in the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: Your program correctly calculates the sum of the first 11 terms of the sequence. This is not a good way to compute pi as the sequence converges very slowly.

Comment: `pow( -1, n )` is the worst way to get alternating signs. Use something like `n % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with it by increasing your iterations.
At "200" I got 3.15.
Basically "10" isn't even close to enough.